# How to align this modal data using boostrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

[image: Image of the problem]

```html
    <div>
          <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.modeltoggle}>
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.modeltoggle}>
              Update User Data
            </ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              <Container>
                <Card className="mx-1 ">
                  <CardBody className="p-4  ">
                    <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                      <Row className="justify-content-center">
                        <Col md="9" lg="8" xl="12">
                          <InputGroup className="mb-3 ">
                            <p className="mt-1 mr-3 font-weight-bold">Name</p>

                            <Input
                              className="mr-3 "
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Data here"
                              name="Name"
                              readOnly
                            />

                            <Input
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Name"
                              name="Name"
                              autoComplete="Name"
                              onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                          </InputGroup>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                      <Row className="justify-content-center">
                        <Col md="9" lg="8" xl="12">
                          <InputGroup className="mb-3 ">
                            <p className="mt-1 mr-3 font-weight-bold">
                              User Name
                            </p>

                            <Input
                              className="mr-3"
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Data here"
                              name="username"
                              readOnly
                            />

                            <Input
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Username"
                              name="username"
                              autoComplete="Username"
                              onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                          </InputGroup>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                      <Row className="justify-content-center">
                        <Col md="9" lg="8" xl="12">
                          <InputGroup className="mb-3 ">
                            <p className="mt-1 mr-3 font-weight-bold">Role</p>

                            <Input
                              className="mr-3"
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Data here"
                              name="Role"
                              readOnly
                            />

                            <Input
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Role"
                              name="Role"
                              autoComplete="Role"
                              onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                          </InputGroup>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                      <Button block color="success">
                        Update
                      </Button>
                    </Form>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Container>
            </ModalBody>
          </Modal>
        </div>
```

I'm new to reactjs web development.
For a project, I want to align all the modal items in the correct order but with the text, I haven't been able to do it properly. I'm using bootstrap in reactjs.
Can anyone help me to set this modal in the correct order using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Check the **Horizontal forms**

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/

Answer (score 0):

please change input rows:

```
<Row>
      <Col xs={12} sm={3}>name</Col>
      <Col xs={12} sm={9}>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={6} sm={6}><input/></Col>
          <Col xs={6} sm={6}><input/></Col>
        </Row>
      </Col>
</Row>
```